# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup, but this time it's NOT a Windows/Console problem!

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, lnk2019

So, the infamous error is back. The project is complaining that it can't find the main() method (that's what the error means, right).

However I do have a main, and my project is a Console project, as it should be. It worked before, so I know it's not that.

Also, the project has too many classes and files for me to post them all, so I will post any classes you need by request.

It's a C++, OpenGL and SDL game on Visual Studio 2010. It's not a problem of any of the libraries, as it was working fine before it suddenly and inexplicably showed this linker error.

EDIT: The main() method:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 glutInit(&argc, argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_ALPHA);
 glutCreateWindow("Game");

 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
 glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
 glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
 glEnable(GL_BLEND);
 glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

 g = Game();
 glutInitWindowSize(g.getScreenWidth(), g.getScreenHeight());
 //glutPositionWindow(1280, 50);

 // Callbacks
 glutDisplayFunc(handleRedraw);
 glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);
 glutMouseFunc(handleMouseClicks);
 glutPassiveMotionFunc(handleMouseOvers);
 glutKeyboardFunc(handleKeyboardEvents);
 glutTimerFunc(50, moveItemToInventory, 0);

 glutMainLoop();

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding the project didn't help?

Comment: @karlphillip, no tried it many times

Comment: Did that started happening after you linked with SDL?

Comment: Nope - I had SDL implementation before. To be honest, I'm not sure what has caused this error, as I have not done anything extreme since it was working - just changed the way some classes work and added new ones.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

SDL_main.h is included automatically from SDL.h, so you always get the nasty #define.

Just write:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#undef main
```

And it should work fine

Comment: I put this those code above my classes
I did that and got more errors:
Error 1 error LNK2005: _main already defined in Main.obj
Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Simulation::simulate(void)" (?simulate@Simulation@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main 
Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_main referenced in function _main

All of the help on here didnt work and i tried everything else and it didnt work... please help

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! (and that IS one wierd #define)

Comment: @ViktorSehr: The rationale is that you can use the same code (`int main() {...}`) in a normal system (Linux, MacOS...) and in Windows. In Windows, to get a program without the console window you have to write `WinMain()` instead of `main()` so SDL replaces your `main()` with `SDL_main()` with that nasty macro and then provides a `WinMain()` in a static library that calls your `SDL_main()` and it just works... except when it doesn't.

Comment: It seems like this probably isn't the way you should do it anymore (if it was once the proper way), given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50087608/574531).

Comment: SDL prefers for your main function to have the form of `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11976179/13341069) gives a more detail explanation of why.

Answer (score 45):

Another option would actually to define your own main with the usual parameters

```
int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    // Your code here
}
```

That should get rid of the error.

Then if you don't use those parameters and you also want to get rid of the compiler warning you could do that trick in your main function.

```
(void)argc;
(void)args;
```

Comment: This is the real solution.  I had `int main(int argc, const char ** argv)` and changing that second param to `char *argv[]` solved the problem.  It even says in the comments for the `main` macro in SDL_main.h: "The application's main() function must be called with C linkage, and should be declared like this: int main(int argc, char *argv[])"

Comment: @megaflop Interesting, which version of SDL are you using now? I'll have to double check the version I used in the past, I think it was 1.2 on the top of my head. If you can confirm it changed with the recent version I'll edit my post and add this detail! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 17):

The default solution from SDL documentation:

tl;dr:

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include "SDL.h"
```

full example:

> Use this function to circumvent failure of SDL_Init() when not using
> SDL_main() as an entry point.

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_SetMainReady();
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    ...

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Source: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady

Comment: Was going to comment this same thing. There's instruction about this in SDL_main.h

Comment: This solved the error I was getting, and seems to be the correct way to do it rather than the old accepted answer.

Comment: This should be selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is likely to be `SDL_main.h`. Check that you don't include that file, there is a nasty define there:

```
#define main SDL_main
```

Comment: I'm not including SDL_main, just SDL and SDL_image, I double-checked

Comment: Worked on DosBox source with Visual Studio 2012 and SDL 1.2.15.