# Why SDL defines main macro?

Tags: c++, sdl, program-entry-point

After having some trouble setting up SDL, I found out that SDL defines a macro that replaces main:

```
#define main SDL_main

// And then
extern C_LINKAGE int SDL_main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

This can also create compilation errors, if the main function doesn't have the `argc` and `argv` parameters defined.

This macro gives me headaches just when I see it... Why does SDL need to redefine main? After some more searching, I found that some people `#undef main`, and use it the normal way.

**So this is the question:** *why does SDL need to redefine main, what does it do? Are there any side effects to undefining it?*

One thing I noticed is that SDL redirects standard output and error to files (and I don't want this behavior), and this behavior stops if I undefine main.

Comment: [You can disable this behavior.](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady)

Comment: Yeesh, lots of anger in this post. The main reason why this is done is to abstract over the different entry point on Windows (winmain) and the traditional entry point on other platforms (int main). It simplifies a lot of code that would otherwise need ifdefs or separate source files. It's a convenience mechanism and can be done manually if you so choose.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Per [the SDL Windows FAQ](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/FAQWindows#I_get_.22Undefined_reference_to_.27SDL_main.27.22_...):

> You should be using `main()` instead of `WinMain()` even though you are creating a Windows application, because SDL provides a version of `WinMain()` which performs some SDL initialization before calling your main code.
>
> If for some reason you need to use `WinMain()`, take a look at the SDL source code in `src/main/win32/SDL_main.c` to see what kind of initialization you need to do in your `WinMain()` function so that SDL works properly.

SDL requires initialization, so it injects its own `main` function that runs its initialization before calling your "main" function, which it renames to `SDL_main` so that it does not conflict with the actual `main` function.  As noted in the FAQ, your `main` function must be of the form

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: Almost every library requires initialization but this looks like a poor practice for how to do it.  +1 anyway.

Comment: @DavidGrayson very poor practice indeed, especially if you have two libraries that do this...massive pain in the patooty

Comment: Can I write my own implementation of main(), instead of using this strange SDL_main() function? There are some things (for example, stdout redirection) that are kind of pushed down my throat, and I don't want it.

Comment: Agree with David. This macro is a C technique. C++ has many sane alternatives.

Comment: Not only I agree with David about this being a poor practice, but SDL has it's own SDL_init call for initialization.
As far as I recall, the initialization in SDLmain was pretty useless (redirection of console if I recall)

Comment: That is misleading in that I had to change my ``main()`` function into ``WinMain()`` anyway then changing the injection from ``main`` to ``WinMain`` in ``SDL_Main.h`` (which I include) to avoid having to ``#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED`` (without handling it). Otherwise the compiler (MinGW + gcc 12) would complain ``WinMain()`` was missing. It seems the SDL team has made an update and didn't care to change the doc accordingly. That seems to make the injection work correctly anyway.

Answer (score 13):

While I agree that it's a strange practice, there are situations where this is a reasonable solution, though it largely depends on the platform. Consider that different platforms have different entry points. Windows is typically WinMain, Linux is main, interacting with Android happens in Java, WinRT uses C++/CX extensions, and so on. Program entry point and APIs can be very platform specific and SDL tries to save you the trouble of having to deal with this. If you're only targeting Windows and SDL is only there to save you the trouble of working with WIN32 API, you might not need it. But if you ever go beyond desktop, you'll find it useful in my opinion.

Comment: "Beyond desktop" — hey! Linux and OsX is deskop too.

Comment: "Windows is typically WinMain" on any MinGW toolchain, you can use standard C or C++ `main` and MinGW will do the job to make it work.

Comment: @Xeverous ; while this may be true, when working with SDL, the compiler will complain about ``Winmain()`` anyway if you're doing the injection "accordingly to the docs".

Comment: @DominicGrenier This is just a weird error message. It will go away if you add `main` or `WinMain` (or link SDL2main properly).