# SDL2: LNK1561: entry point must be defined

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, sdl, sdl-2

I want to compile this code:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

But it can't be linked: `Error 1 error LNK1561: entry point must be defined`

There is some strange code in this library: http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/75726efbf679/include/SDL_main.h

```
#define main    SDL_main
```

Also I added `SDL2.lib;SDL2main.lib` to Project Settings => Linker => Input.

What can I do to run this project?
VS 2012 SP3, empty C++ project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why SDL defines main macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976084/why-sdl-defines-main-macro)

Comment: @MikeSeymour, it's not a duplicate: that thread doesn't contain an answer.

Comment: @computer, yes, console.

Comment: I just started learning c and encountered the same error, this error means something not right with `main()`, in my code I had it misspelled as `Main` with capital m, after correcting it the error disappeared.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179230-fatal-error-lnk1561-entry-point-must-be-defined/) on Dream.In.Code:

> Right click on project name -> Properties -> Expand Linker tab -> System -> SubSystem: make sure that it is `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`

Alternatively, if you want to hide the console window or are [debugging a multithreaded application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672303/sdl2-lnk1561-entry-point-must-be-defined/18672451#comment87620822_18672451), you should set the SubSystem to `Window (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOW)` instead.

Comment: Adding that if you can get int main() to compile on its own then do make sure you've checked your compiler settings as mentioned here, as depending on how you've created your project may mean this setting is not done for you already. As was my problem.

Comment: I'm adding to this answer. If you are debugging an SDL2 app, and you've added multithreading to said app, instead of using `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`, use `Window (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOW)`. This should also let Visual Studio 2017 attach its local debugger to your SDL2 app successfully, allowing you to debug multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: Out of time to edit my last comment... Reason why you must go with `Window (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOW)` is because `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` is single-threaded only.

Answer (score 7):

I have found that setting */SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE* is only half of the solution. The second half is to add `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` to your additional defines. The clue I used to resolve this can be found in *SDL_main.h*. Setting `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` tell the SDL header files that you've already provided a `main` function and do not wish for it to redefine its own entry point.

Comment: This is the correct way to solve this problem - good debugging skills @dpiron. If your project is set up correctly to begin with you shouldn't need to change Linker properties at this stage

Comment: To add more information to what @user3001499 is referring to, you need to start with a **win32** application project, see [VisualC.html](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/raw-file/0d5da1145cad/VisualC.html).

Answer (score 4):

**DON'T** `#undef main`! while its a really bad practice on the SDL side to redefine it, they have good reasons: `WinMain` is defined on the library side and used to run some init code, helping with compatibility issues. (even more when using different SDL implementations, like Steam's or porting to other platforms like Android)

So what should you do? When on Windows, you should always include `SDL2main.lib` before `SDL2.lib` and make sure your main is in the format:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) // CORRECT
void main(int argc, char* argv[]) // WRONG
int main(int, char**) // MAY BE CORRECT
```

Source: [SDL2 Windows FAQ](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows)

Comment: The `int main(int, char**)` is correct too. Also, what's about Steam SDL implementation? Google doesn't seem to know about it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation#SteamOS SDL provide a dynamic loader and steam is known to include it's own copy of SDL which is different for SteamOSes

Comment: Note that it's also necessary to create a **win32** application project. See [VisualC.html](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/raw-file/0d5da1145cad/VisualC.html).

Answer (score 1):

As a *tinky_winki* wrote

> Right click on project name -> Properties -> Expand Linker tab ->
>   System -> SubSystem: make sure that it is Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)

But if you don't expect console with window simply use, **/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS**

Comment: Who is *tinky_winki*? Where did they write this?

Answer (score 0):

Project >> Properties >> Linker >> Advanced >> entry point = main
and apply

Answer (score -1):

Open **sdl_main.h**

Change

```cpp
#define main sdl_main
```

to

```cpp
#define sdl_main main
```

now it will work with simple **int main()** but this is bad hooray to short term solutions

Comment: This makes zero sense. It's no different from `#undef main`, except you're modifying the library headers.