# LNK1561 entry point must be defined - SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

I got a LNK1561 entry point must be defined error i tried somethings my self as stsyem settings to console and it still doesn't work. Here is my code for every class the SDl.h is from the SDL.h donwload page.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MainGame.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

std::cout << "Enter any ket to quit...";
int a;
std::cin >> a;

return 0;

}
```

MainGame.cpp:

```
#include "MainGame.h"

MainGame::MainGame()
{

_window = nullptr;
_screenHeight = 1028;
_screenWidth = 768;

}


MainGame::~MainGame()
{
}

void MainGame::run() {
    InitSystems();
}

void MainGame::InitSystems() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    _window = SDL_CreateWindow("title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1028, 768, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    }
```

MainGame.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <SDL/SDL.h>

class MainGame
{
public:
    MainGame();
    ~MainGame();

    void run();

    void InitSystems();

private:
    SDL_Window* _window;
    int _screenWidth;
    int _screenHeight;
};
```

Allt his code is to open an Windowed frame on your computer en open an console with the text Press Any ket to quit... If i remove the SDL.h include and the SDL code it all works if i put the include back and not the SDL code it gives the error again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SDL2: LNK1561: entry point must be defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672303/sdl2-lnk1561-entry-point-must-be-defined)

Comment: no i tried every thing from that post to and did not work

Comment: @Yorick Have you tried using MainGame in your main function? Chances that the compiler assumes that it is never used and you do not get the `#include <SDL/SDL.h>` directive to work. Also, consider changing `#include <SDL/SDL.h>` to `#include "SDL/SDL.h"`.

Comment: @SerkanPekçetin i have changed the include to "SDL/SDL.h" and still getting same error :(

Comment: Can you try [this](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady)

Comment: @SerkanPekçetin got new error when i did this:

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include "MainGame.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

SDL_SetMainReady();
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

SDL_Quit();

return 0;

}

Comment: errors:

Error   LNK1120 4 unresolved externals  Game    
C:\Users\yoric\source\repos\Game\Debug\Game.exe 1   

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _SDL_SetMainReady referenced in 
function _main  Game    C:\Users\yoric\source\repos\Game\Game\main.obj  1   

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function 
_main   Game    C:\Users\yoric\source\repos\Game\Game\main.obj  1

Comment: Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init    Game    
C:\Users\yoric\source\repos\Game\Game\MainGame.obj  1   

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _SDL_Quit referenced in function 
_main   Game    C:\Users\yoric\source\repos\Game\Game\main.obj  1   

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _SDL_CreateWindow referenced in 
function "public: void __thiscall MainGame::InitSystems(void)" (?
InitSystems@MainGame@@QAEXXZ)   Game    
C:\Users\yoric\source\repos\Game\Game\MainGame.obj  1

Comment: @SerkanPekçetin your suggestion fixed the entry point issue for me. Suggest making an answer out of it.

Comment: @MattBrown Glad that helped. I have just put it as an answer per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using MainGame in your main function? Chances that the compiler assumes that it is never used and you do not get the `#include <SDL/SDL.h>` directive to work. Also, consider changing `#include <SDL/SDL.h>` to `#include "SDL/SDL.h"`.

Also you might consider using [SDL_SetMainReady](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady) for the cases that you are not using `SDL_Main` as the entry point.