# How to catch argv null exception?

Tags: c++, exception

In my program I pass an argument from console and save it to a variable. Let's say

```
const  string FileName= argv[1];
```

If there is no argument passing I get this

```
terminate called throwing an exception
```

How can I catch an exception and show proper error to user that there is no arguments passed?

Comment: You don't. You check `argc` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argc` gives you the size of `argv`, so check its value before accessing `argv`. Remember that `argv` is zero-based, so has bounds `argv[0, ..., arrc - 1]`. Helpfully, `argv[argc]` is always set to NULL.

Accessing an invalid element of `argv` is *undefined behaviour*.

As a final remark, `argv[0]` (if it isn't NULL) is the program name.

Comment: (Actually, it is `[0, argc]`. The last is guaranteed to be `NULL`. See 3.6.1/2)

Comment: Actually `argv[argc]` is a valid entry. It should also always be `NULL` (which is the problem for the OP, he's trying to assign a `NULL` pointer to a `std::string`).

Comment: Isn't the zero element of argv initialized in any case as it was echo? So 1 means  you have 1 parameter in argv[1]? or I remember wrong?

Comment: @Zaibis The name the program was executed with goes in `argv[0]` (or, according to The Standard, `""` is allowed instead), but that is counted in `argc`. So if `argc` is `1`, the program was executed with no extra arguments.

Comment: @BoBTFish, I wasn't aware of that. I've amended the answer.

Comment: ah ok so argc will never be `argc < 1`?

Comment: @Zaibis, you ought not rely on this. Always check `argc` for safety; someone else may be using `main`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Would you mind clarifying that? Do you mean things like [SDL, that may hijack `main` to do some initialisation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11976084/1171191)?

Comment: Well, so argc SHOULD be never less then 1?

Comment: @BoBTFish; indeed. I'm sure Windows 3.1 and earlier were particularly 'good' at hijacking the main function but can't recall the mechanism they used. But I am super-paranoid when it comes to overrunning array buffers; particularly in pure C.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you just should check the value of `argc`, as it holds the amount of parameters which are parsed to argv.

Comment: I don't understand your first line. Can you please clarify what you mean by "checking stder used as descriptor"?

Comment: My fault I mixed something sorry

Answer (score 1):

Your main has two arguments - `argv` and `argc`. While `argv` stores the arguments passed to your program `argc` stores their count. So you can check if an argument was provided to your program by checking the value of `argc`.

Keep in mind, though, that the first value in argv is the executable name, so if you want to check that a argument was passed to your program you should have a check like:

```
if (argc >= 2) {
  ... do stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check `argc` as in:

```
const  string FileName= (argc < 2)?string():argv[1];
```

As for your specific question, you catch exceptions by means of a try/catch block as in

```
try{
exceptionThrowingOperation();
}
catch( ThrownExceptionType& e ){
exceptionHandling(e);
}
```