# error : unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmaincrtstartup

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm having this error : "unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmaincrtstartup" just compiling this little code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    return 0;
}
```

The error pops only when I include SDL.h. I've already tried to go to Properties -> Linker -> System and change sub-system to console or windows same result.

What should I do ?

EDIT : Okay apparently this was due to the fact that I was using the SDL 32 bits instead of the 64. Now I'm having a warning but I should be able to fix it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Is `tmaincrtstartup` an `inline` function defined in `SDL.h`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits `___tmaincrtstartup` is from the win32 C runtime MSVCRT.lib

Comment: Make sure your project default calling convention is cdecl, or explicitly make you main function __cdecl.

Comment: I just checked it's alreadu cdecl

Comment: Sorry for the false lead. I later realized that [`SDL.h` contains a `#define main SDL_main`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976084/why-sdl-defines-main-macro), which is why your declaration of `main` doesn't actually define `main`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add both SDL.lib and SDLmain.lib to your linker.

Comment: I've already done that too. I've added SDL.lib SDLmain.lib and SDLtest.lib