# undefined reference to `WinMain@16' error while linking SDL1.2 in cmake for MinGW

Tags: cmake, static-linking, sdl-1.2

I recently managed to find solution to this problem related to SDL2, but somehow those solutions does not apply to SDL1.2. I tried using the flags `-lmingw32 -lSDL -lSDLmain` and also to add `add_definitions(-DSDL_MAIN_HANDLED)` to the end of the CMakeLists.txt file. However I still get the following error message:

```
====================[ Build | Graphics_project | Debug ]========================
"A:\CLion 2019.2.5\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\Coding\Projects\Graphics_project\cmake-build-debug --target Graphics_project -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable Graphics_project.exe
D:/Coding/MSYS2/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Coding/MSYS2/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function `main':
D:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [Graphics_project.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Graphics_project.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Graphics_project.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Graphics_project.dir\build.make:85: recipe for target 'Graphics_project.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:74: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Graphics_project.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Graphics_project.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'Graphics_project' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Graphics_project] Error 2
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Graphics_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

find_package(SDL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(Graphics_project main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL_LIBRARY})
add_definitions(-DSDL_MAIN_HANDLED)
```

And in a separate `cmake` folder in the project folder I have a `FindSDL.cmake` file:

```
set(FIND_SDL_PATHS D:/Coding/Devs/SDL-devel-1.2.15-mingw32/SDL-1.2.15)

find_path(SDL_INCLUDE_DIR SDL
        PATH_SUFFIXES include
        PATHS ${FIND_SDL_PATHS})

find_library(SDL_LIBRARY
        NAMES SDL SDLmain
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib
        PATHS ${FIND_SDL_PATHS})
```

I'am trying to compile a simple "Hello World":

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate some help, I just don't understand how is it different from the SDL2 library linking.

Comment: `add_definitions` is commented out and therefore the setting is not applied.

Comment: I commented it out because it did not have any effect. But I edit it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why SDL defines main macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976084/why-sdl-defines-main-macro)

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the `WIN32` option in `add_executable()`.

```
add_executable(Graphics_project WIN32 main.cpp)
```

On of the quirks of Windows is that GUI applications (not console applications) replace the entry point (the first function that is called, usually `main()`) of your program with `WinMain()` which in turn calles the `main()` function after some setup. The WIN32 switch makes sure that this function gets generated.