# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup error

Tags: c++, sdl, lnk2019

I am programming SDL in C++ and I keep getting an error:

```
    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
```

What can I do to resolve this? Here is my source:

```
#include <SDL.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window* Window = NULL;
    Window = SDL_CreateWindow("Render Window",0,0,1000,1000, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN || SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
    return 0;
}
```

My linker and compiler seem fine, I have included console in the subsystem etc. But the error only occurs when I add:

```
#include <SDL.h>
```

Comment: Also interesting [Why SDL defines main macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976084/why-sdl-defines-main-macro)

Comment: This question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847360/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-tmainc)

Comment: I'm not sure why you've decided to get into an edit war with yourself, but I'm locking this post.

Answer (score 10):

I think "SDL.h" internally includes "SDL_main.h", which contains a weird `#define`:

```
#define main SDL_main
```

which is almost certainly screwing up your own `main`.

Try adding `#undef main` after include "SDL.h", e.g.:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#undef main
```

Since you said you have already changed `SubSystem` to `Console`, that should be all you need.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847360/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-tmainc) for more information.

Comment: Also, it's important that **Character Set** be configured to `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`.