# C++ SDL Errors that i've researched, still cant fix

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to compile this.

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Shows me these errors:

> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Quit referenced
>   in function
>   _SDL_main C:\Users\Scrub\Desktop\C++\SDL__tutorial\main.obj
>
> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced
>   in function
>   _SDL_main C:\Users\Scrub\Desktop\C++\SDL__tutorial\main.obj
>
> Error 3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in
>   function
>   ___tmainCRTStartup    C:\Users\Scrub\Desktop\C++\SDL__tutorial\MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
>
> Error 4   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved
>   externals C:\Users\Scrub\Desktop\C++\SDL__tutorial\Debug\SDL__tutorial.exe    1

I've tried searching these errors everywhere; tried all the supposed fixes, it still does this.

Edit - I've somewhat fixed this(By switching to x86 lib and #undef main), but now when i build and launch it, it shows an application error

The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000007b)

**Still produces almost the same errors with windows subsystem**

Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup C:\Users\Scrub\Desktop\C++\SDL__tutorial\MSVCRT.lib(crtexew.obj)

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Quit referenced in function _SDL_main    C:\Users\Scrub\Desktop\C++\SDL__tutorial\main.obj

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function _SDL_main    C:\Users\Scrub\Desktop\C++\SDL__tutorial\main.obj

Error   4   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Scrub\Desktop\C++\SDL__tutorial\Debug\SDL__tutorial.exe

Comment: possible duplicate of [error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol \_main referenced in function \_\_\_tmainCRTStartup, but this time it's NOT a Windows/Console problem!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847360/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-tmainc)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Visual Studio? It seems like your linker can't find your main function. Right click on your project, go to Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System and try changing the Subsystem to either Console or Windows, whichever one works ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845410/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-tmainc)). I don't know which supposed fixes you've tried, so hopefully this one solves your issue.

I'm new to Stackoverflow so I hope I did this right and that this helps!