# install cURLpp errors c++

Tags: c++, curl, curlpp

I recently installed cURLpp from NUGET in visual studio. Everything installed correctly and when I try to use cURLpp I get the following error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_setopt referenced in function "public: void __thiscall curlpp::internal::CurlHandle::option<void *>(enum CURLoption,void *)" (??$option@PAX@CurlHandle@internal@curlpp@@QAEXW4CURLoption@@PAX@Z) Project1 C:\Users\Joel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj 1
```

This error stops happening when I remove #include Options.hpp

IDE: Visual Studio 2015, Compiling on Windows 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol \_main referenced in function "int \_\_cdecl invoke\_main(void)" (?invoke\_main@@YAHXZ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400777/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-int-cde)