# I get a LNK2019 Error in 'Hello World' program

Tags: c++, lnk2019

I have just started an online course on C++ using MS Visual Studio 2019 community Edition
Here's the program:

```
// Program 1_1
// Our first program!
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
system("pause");
}`
```

I get the LNK2019 error - unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int__cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
I'm running Windows 2010 64 bit professional edition
Can anyone help me with this error?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: @paisanco no it will not help in this case.

Comment: Please post the full build log, not just the error message.

Comment: Program is fine so it must be the project settings.  Create a new project in MSVS 2019 and make sure you choose project type __Console App__. Then build and run the project with it's default settings.

Comment: Just to expand on the comment from @RichardCritten: Windows has this weird ting that GUI applications has typically `WinMain` as entry function, while console applications has `main` as entry function.

Comment: If you want to have a console window and not have to create a GUI window, then you need to make sure you choose a "Console" project type and not a "Windows" project type. A console app has access to standard input and output via the console window that is automatically created.  Have you ever noticed that when you start a normal windows GUI app it doesn't pop up a console window? If you make a console app then your program will always pop up a console - so the reason you make a normal windows GUI app is so that you don't automatically get a console window when you double click.

Comment: I followed Richard C's advice (thanks Richard) & created a Solution choosing the project type **Console App**. When I had done that, it had a Hello World example that I could run just fine.
I closed that file then created my own.  When I ran Debug on it, it always debugged the original example, not my code.
I closed the solution & re-opened it having only my code open.  When I debugged it, it still ran the original example.  I do not understand why.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This complies to me if I remove the "`"

There are a few advices here for this issue:
[Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400777/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-int-cde)

Comment: The  "`" is one of SO's formatting characters (used to quote code) and is a simple typo.  If you think the link is an exact match then flag the post as a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe it's not exactly the same but I think it suggests that it's a Linker setup issue.