# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) (1 unresolved externals)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Code:

```
#include "includes.h"
#include "no_renderer/FW1FontWrapper/FW1FontWrapper.h"
#include "no_renderer/no_menu/no_menu.h"
#include "no_renderer/no_gui/no_gui.h"
#include "no_define.h"
#include "fstream"
#include "no_cheat/no_spoofcall.h"
#include "no_cheat/framework.h"
#include "no_cheat/Esp.h"
#include "no_cheat/Aimbot.h"
#include "no_cheat/Exploits.h"
#include "no_cheat/PawnsLoop.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "windowscodecs.lib")


//typedef HRESULT(*present_fn)(IDXGISwapChain*, UINT, UINT);
//inline present_fn original_present{ };

//typedef HRESULT(*resize_fn)(IDXGISwapChain*, UINT, UINT, UINT, DXGI_FORMAT, UINT);
//inline resize_fn original_resize{ };
```

The full code is here: https://github.com/SantaaVibez/FortniteRageCheatSource/blob/main/1337/dllmain.cpp

How do I fix this?

I tried adding windowscodecs.lib to the code, and it didn't change anything, any fixes?

Comment: The error says you dont have a main method. Which seems to be true from what code you posted.

Comment: I have a DllMain though

Comment: It's so pose to be a dll and not an executable too...

Comment: Then you need to change your compiler options so that it's compiling to a shared library, not an executable. In visual studio, go to the projects properties to change this setting.

Comment: You used to the wrong project template to get started.  It is trying to build a .exe file, not a .dll, a .exe requires a main() entrypoint.  Project > Properties > General > "Configuration Type" should be Dynamic Library

Comment: Try suggestion provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400777/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-int-cde